# Como passar um objeto para o construtor de uma widget em DOJO javascript?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando passar um objeto que criei como parâmetro no construtor de um widget. O objeto até vai e consigo setar minha propriedade com ele, mas assim que ele sai do Construtor ele quebra.

Aqui é onde eu crio o objeto e tento passar ele como parâmetro para o construtor da minha widget:

```
var mapa = new Mapa("mapa", "basemapGallery", "layerList");
var atualizaWidget = new AtualizaWidget(mapa);
```

Este é o código da minha Widget, ele quebra bem quando sai do construtor:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojo/text!./widget/templates/AtualizaTemplate.html"

], function (declare, dom, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, template) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        objMapa: null,

        templateString: template,

        constructor: function (objMap) {
            this.objMapa = objMap;
        },

        //Ele quebra bem aqui quando sai

        postCreate: function () {
            //console.log(this.objMapa);
        }
    });

});
```

dando a seguinte mensagem:

> TypeError: c is undefined...][a-zA-Z]*$/.test(a)?a.toLowerCase():a;c.tagName?l.set(c,b,g):c.set(b,g);break;c...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo na tentativa e erro. Não sei porquê assim funcionou, mas eu tive que passar as propriedades individualmente, ficando assim:

```
var atualizaWidget = new AtualizaWidget({
    'mapa': mapa.mapa,
    'url': mapa.layerUrl
});
```

De qualquer forma, muito obrigado.